# Unset Category if other Category is unset during post transition

Tags: functions, categories

I am trying to unset a category if another category is unset.

First i have a function that add's category if another category is set such as:

```
function add_category_automatically($post_ID) {
    global $wpdb;
    if ( in_category('3152') ) {
        $cat = array(1208);
        wp_set_object_terms($post_ID, $cat, 'category', true);
    }
}
```

add_action('save_post', 'add_category_automatically');

This adds category with id 1208 if post has category with id 3152.

Now i need a function that does the exact reverse, that if category with id 3152 is unset i need the function to also unset category with id 1208.

I understand i could simply do something like this, but it will screw things up because i want the end user to be able to set category with id 1208 by itself, it should only be removed if category with id 3152 is removed.

```
function remove_category_automatically($post_ID) {
    global $wpdb;
    if ( !in_category('3152') ) {
        $cat = array(1208);
        wp_remove_object_terms($post_ID, $cat, 'category', true);
    }
}
```

add_action('save_post', 'remove_category_automatically');

Thus this code above doesn't work because with this code you cannot set category 1208 by it self, it will always remove 1208 unless 3152 is present, i want some posts to have category 1208 without having cat 3152.

So i try something like this but it's not really working.

```
function on_all_status_transitions( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
    if ( in_category('3152') ) {
        if ( $new_status != $old_status && has_category('3152') ) {
            $cat = array(3152);
            wp_remove_object_terms($post_ID, $cat, 'category', true);
        }
    }
}
```

add_action(  'transition_post_status',  'on_all_status_transitions', 10, 3 );

Any ideas how to solve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What hook are you using for this?

Comment: added the hooks i used for the code in the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `deleted_term_relationships` action to check if some term is removed from a post object.

This hook is in the [`wp_remove_object_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remove_object_terms/)

```
function custom_remove_category( $object_id, $tt_ids, $taxonomy ) {
    if( $taxonomy == 'category' ) {
        if( in_array( 3152, $tt_ids ) ) {
            wp_remove_object_terms( $object_id, [1208], 'category' );
        }
    }
    return $object_id;
}
add_action( 'deleted_term_relationships', 'custom_remove_category', 10, 3 );
```